# Distro 'ubuntu18.04' does not exist in our dictionary

Tags: server, 18.04, kvm-virtualization, minecraft, qemu

(Ubuntu greenhorn here)

I am running Ubuntu server 18.04 on my bare metal, with a couple of VMs running presently which are 14.04. I am having no issues whatsoever with the 14.04 servers running for Plex Media Server and Minecraft, but I am trying to mess with a Minecraft Bedrock (mobile edition) server, which is said to need Ubuntu 18.04 to operate. I am trying to get the VM to spin up, but I get an error saying that ubuntu 18.04 doesn't exist. I am really stuck, and not sure what to do from here. I saw it only goes up to 17.04 and 17.10 when looking at "osinfo-query os".

I COULD attempt to run the software on the bare metal server, but being a 14TB NAS with running VMs, I'd rather not, as this is Alpha software at this point. I would just like to get an 18.04 VM kicked up.

Here is what I am using, and the error it presents.

```
ziggidy@zeus:~/ISOs$ sudo virt-install \
> --name Hermes \
> --description "Minecraft VM" \
> --os-type=Linux \
> --os-variant=ubuntu18.04 \
> --ram=16384 \
> --vcpus=8 \
> --disk path=/home/ziggidy/VMs/Drive2/Hermes.img,bus=virtio,size=50 \
> --network bridge:br0 \
> --graphics none \
> --location /home/ziggidy/ISOs/ubuntu-14.04.5-server-amd64.iso \
> --extra-args console=ttyS0
[sudo] password for ziggidy:
ERROR    Error validating install location: Distro 'ubuntu18.04' does not exist in our dictionary
ziggidy@zeus:~/ISOs$
```

Here is a "successful" use with 14.04. I aborted it as I don't need another 14.04 vm at the moment, and the software won't run in 14.04.

```
ziggidy@zeus:~/ISOs$ sudo virt-install \
> --name Hermes \
> --description "Minecraft VM" \
> --os-type=Linux \
> --os-variant=ubuntu14.04 \
> --ram=16384 \
> --vcpus=8 \
> --disk path=/home/ziggidy/VMs/Drive2/Hermes.img,bus=virtio,size=50 \
> --network bridge:br0 \
> --graphics none \
> --location /home/ziggidy/ISOs/ubuntu-14.04.5-server-amd64.iso \
> --extra-args console=ttyS0

Starting install...
Retrieving file .treeinfo...                                                                                                                                                                                          |    0 B  00:00:00
Retrieving file content...                                                                                                                                                                                            |    0 B  00:00:00
Retrieving file info...                                                                                                                                                                                               |   66 B  00:00:00
Retrieving file vmlinuz...                                                                                                                                                                                            | 6.6 MB  00:00:00
Retrieving file initrd.gz...                                                                                                                                                                                          |  11 MB  00:00:00
^C^CDomain install interrupted.
Installation aborted at user request
^C
ziggidy@zeus:~/ISOs$ ^C
```

I gave it yet another shot with OS variant removed, and get a different error.

```
ziggidy@zeus:~/ISOs$ sudo virt-install \
> --name Hermes \
> --description "Bedrock Minecraft VM" \
> --os-type=Linux \
> --ram=2048 \
> --vcpus=2 \
> --disk path=/home/ziggidy/VMs/Drive2/Hermes.img,bus=virtio,size=50 \
> --network bridge:br0 \
> --graphics none \
> --location /home/ziggidy/ISOs/ubuntu-18.04.1-live-server-amd64.iso \
> --extra-args console=ttyS0
WARNING  No operating system detected, VM performance may suffer. Specify an OS with --os-variant for optimal results.

Starting install...
Retrieving file .treeinfo...                                                                                                                                                                                          |    0 B  00:00:00
Retrieving file content...                                                                                                                                                                                            |    0 B  00:00:00
Retrieving file info...                                                                                                                                                                                               |   70 B  00:00:00
Retrieving file info...                                                                                                                                                                                               |   70 B  00:00:00
Retrieving file info...                                                                                                                                                                                               |   70 B  00:00:00
ERROR    Couldn't find hvm kernel for Ubuntu tree.
Domain installation does not appear to have been successful.
If it was, you can restart your domain by running:
  virsh --connect qemu:///system start Hermes
otherwise, please restart your installation.
ziggidy@zeus:~/ISOs$
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu does your host run? Is it up to date?

Comment: Thank you Michael. This is embarrassing, but 'sudo apt-get update' and 'sudo apt-get upgrade' did the trick with regards to the unknown distro issue. Unfortunately I am still getting the "Couldn't find hvm kernel for Ubuntu tree." error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Couldn't find hvm kernel for Ubuntu tree](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1116383/couldnt-find-hvm-kernel-for-ubuntu-tree)

Answer (score 3):

virt-install get's it's os information out of [osinfo-db](https://gitlab.com/libosinfo/osinfo-db)

If your os does not ship a recent version of osinfo-db you can manually download it from https://releases.pagure.org/libosinfo/ and import it.
e.g.

```
wget https://releases.pagure.org/libosinfo/osinfo-db-20211013.tar.xz
osinfo-db-import -v osinfo-db-20211013.tar.xz
```

Sometimes even osinfo-db is not up to date yet, I found out I had to use fedora31 whilst fedora32 is out for a few weeks now, but there shouldn't be to much of a difference I believe.

Comment: Where is `osinfo-db-import` from?

Answer (score 0):

```
ERROR    Error validating install location: Distro 'ubuntu18.04' does not exist in our dictionary
```

was resolved by running simple update

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```