# Non-live Ubuntu Server 20.04 release

Tags: 20.04

We've been using the "non-live" Ubuntu Server release. We use [Kickstart](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KickstartCompatibility) to automate installations. From experience, we know our Kickstart setup does not work with the live images.

It seems like the non-live server images (`ubuntu-20.04-server-amd64.iso`) have been dropped for 20.04, and only live server images are supported (`ubuntu-20.04-live-server-amd64.iso`). Non of the [mirrors](http://ubuntu-releases.mirror.nucleus.be/20.04/) serve it. Is this correct? Can I somehow build it myself?

Comment: Are you sure you cannot use the 'live' server image?   A lot of testing, and requests for testing went out with the purpose of refining the server image so it could cope with all use cases, and whilst it had a lot of limitations earlier on, it was in this testing that eventually the 'live' only option was decided possible.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Actually, the "non-live" server image is still available for Ubuntu 20.04. It's now being called "**legacy server image**" and you can find it [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-legacy-server/releases/20.04/release/). How did I find it? Well, it's listed in the [release note](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes#Get_Ubuntu_20.04.3_LTS) for Focal.

Comment: Well spotted! It's not helpful that the non-live server image isn't at all well signposted from the main Ubuntu download pages, however. I'm having problems trying to boot/install the new-style server image on a VM, so will try this. (See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1241050/booting-ubuntu-20-04-live-server-amd64-iso-on-vmware-virtual-machine-fails)

Comment: Thank you!  The Live installer is one of the worst things Ubuntu ever did.  It is absolutely horrible.

Comment: Absolutely! I've had nothing but problems with the live-installers. Several different machines, both desktops and enterprise server hardware, it just never works right.